# regex is null in javascript but not in php

Tags: javascript, php, regex

I have this text

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `arrivals` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `jobid` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `eta` int(32) NOT NULL,
  `keyword` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `url` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `searchengine` varchar(3) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'de' COMMENT 'Suchmaschine',
  `keywordid` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `urlid` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=2040 ;
```

in php this regex works

`preg_match_all ( "#(CREATE.*?);#s", $_POST["sql"], $matches );`

in javascript this regex returns null. why?

`var result          = textAreaText.match(/(CREATE.*?);/gm);`

Comment: the value is the text i've provided.

Comment: Uses different modifiers... expects same result... `s` = DOTALL, `m` = MULTILINE

Comment: maybe i'm using different modifiers because s doesn't work in javascript and g in javascript is the same as preg_match_all in php?

Comment: `g` is good. That is correct. However DOTALL and MULTILINE are not the same ;)

Comment: Yeah. I just tried all modifiers that were available since the s one didn't work. That's why it's in. :)

Comment: Heh, believe me, I made similar mistakes early on ;) Now I just use `[^\x00]` because it looks cool XD

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Javascript doesn't have `s` flag (DOTALL) so you can use:

```
var result = textAreaText.match(/(CREATE[\s\S]*?);/g);
```

DOT otherwise matches any character other than newline but use of `[\s\S]` makes it match any character and newline as well.

Also you don't really need `m` modifier here since that is used for using anchors `^ and $` in a `MULTILINE` input.